# Need two functions always be composed to prove they are inverses?

Tags: functions, inverse

Normally, if I claimed that $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow A$ were inverses of each other, I would check for the following results: $f \circ g(b) = b$ and $g \circ f(a) = a$.

Suppose I knew, however, that $f$ is bijective. And suppose I knew that $g$ is a working pre-image mapping. Then, can I claim that $g$ is the inverse of $f$, even if I haven't composed $g$ with $f$? A concrete example:

---

Suppose we proved that $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x) = x^{3}$ is a bijection. As part of proving surjectivity of $f$, we found for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ an $x$ such that $f(x) = y$. In particular, we decided to let $x = y^{1/3}$.

Can I safely claim that $h(y) = y^{1/3}$ is $f^{-1}$ without needing to compose $h$ with $f$?

I would think so, since if $f$ is a bijection, then its inverse is also a bijection and well-defined. Thus, am I right that composition is not the only means to proving two functions are inverses?

Comment: You are saying "Suppose we proved that f ... is a bijection.  ... Can I safely claim that h(y) = $y^{1/3}$ is $f^{-1}$?".  In other words, you are asking that if you *already* know f is a bijection, then do you have to check h of f, correct?

Comment: Just a comment, but many functions are shown to have inverses without computing the inverse. For instance, you can show in your example that the function is strictly increasing and therefore 1-1. Also since it gets arbitrarily large in both directions it is bijective. If you have a candidate as you say, the usual thing to do to verify that it is indeed the inverse is to check the result of composition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, *if you know $f$ is bijective*, you can skip one of the verifications. This follows because *inverses are unique*.

If $f:A \to B$ is a bijection, there is a **unique** function $f^{-1}:B \to A$ such that $f\circ f^{-1} = \mathrm{id}_B$ and $f^{-1} \circ f = \mathrm{id}_A$.

If you show that $g \circ f = \mathrm{id}_A$ then $g=g \circ \mathrm{id}_B = g \circ (f\circ f^{-1}) = (g \circ f) \circ f^{-1} = \mathrm{id}_A \circ f^{-1} = f^{-1}$. Therefore, since $g=f^{-1}$, the other composition comes for free.

Comment: I see how you concluded that $g = f^{-1}$. Does your argument really depend on the uniqueness of the inverse, however -- or on the fact that an inverse, regardless if it is unique, **exists** as a result of bijectivity? Thanks!

Comment: My argument doesn't rely on uniqueness, but the result itself is really a direct consequence of uniqueness. :)

Comment: Essentially  $g$ must be the inverse because it behaves like the inverse.

Answer (score 1):

Your set-up: we found for any $y∈\Bbb R$ an x such that $f(x)=y$. In particular, we decided to let $x=y^{1/3}$. ... $h(y)=y^{1/3}$.

Then this is an inverse function.  Since $f(x)=y$ and $h(y)=y^{1/3}=x$, then these two statements imply $h(f(x))=x$ for all $x$.

So the only thing you are really "avoiding" checking is that $f(h(y)) = y$.  The way you can see that is:

$h\circ$ $f(h(y)) = (h\circ f)(h(y)) = h(y)$, since we know that $h\circ f=\iota$

So $h\circ$ $f(h(y)) = h\circ y$ for all $y$; and since $h$ is a bijection, then this implies $f(h(y)) = y$ for all $y$.  So yes, you get it for free when proving that $f$ a bijection.